# How to create a blocked hanging indent report format in R (preferably using gt)

Tags: r, report, kable, flextable, gt

I want to report data in R using the display format like an MS Access block grouped report, that is, where the data that is duplicated on the subsequent lines of a group is omitted.

```r
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)


df = tribble( ~a, ~b, ~c,
             'a', 'b', 'c',
             'a', 'b', 'd',
             'a', 'b', 'e',
             '1', 'b', 'c',
             '1', 'b', 'd',
             '1', 'b', 'e')
```

Desired output here (if you can imagine the red to be cut out)

[image]

I tried 2 different things.  The plain gt() call comes close, but I want to get rid of the duplicated values, e.g. the values a/b in rows 2-3 and 1/b in rows 5-6.s

```
df %>% gt()
```

[image: plain gt() output]

First, I grouped by 2 columns, but then I lost my column level formatting, and descriptive headers.

```
df %>%
  group_by( a, b) %>%
  gt()
```

[image: grouped gt output]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can turn the duplicated values to blank -

```
df[duplicated(df[1:2]), 1:2] <- ''
gt::gt(df)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
df %>%
    mutate(across(1:2, ~ replace(., duplicated(.), ""))) %>%
    gt()
```